# Need help to solve complex sql query with django queryset

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-queryset

I need help to translate a sql query to a django queryset...
I have tried many things but nothing that can solve it

The query below is exactly what I need and it actually give me the result I expect. Can anyone help me on this case ?

```
SELECT DISTINCT on (name) *
    FROM my_table
    WHERE (name, job_result_id) = ANY(
             SELECT name, max(job_result_id) 
             FROM my_table
             WHERE ticket != ''
             GROUP BY name, job_result_id)
```

An typical example:

```
name          result     ticket     job_result_id

aaaa          pass                  1
aaaa          fail       MCB2       2
aaaa          fail       MCB3       3
bbbb          fail       MCB25      3
cccc          pass                  4
dddd          fail       MCB6       4
```

My sql return:

```
name          result     ticket     job_result_id

aaaa          fail       MCB3       3
bbbb          fail       MCB25      3
dddd          fail       MCB6       4
```

I always want the last job_result_id or the latest distinct value with a ticket.
Maybe if someone has a better idea about the sql query. I'm open to the discussion.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you add your model and what is your expected result from a query?

Comment: I added an example of how look my table and what kind of result I expect

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
YOU_MODEL.objects.filter(ticket__isnull=False).distinct('name').annotate(max_job_result_id=Max('job_result_id')).values('name', 'job_result_id', 'max_job_result_id')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it and I got this error: 
annotate() + distinct(fields) is not implemented.